# Executing command used in bash script

Tags: bash, scripting, tcpdump

I'm trying to run a tcpdump command in a bash script, but I keep getting this error : `tcpdump: illegal token: "`

My script can be summarized by :

`a='sudo tcpdump "icmp"'
echo $a
$a`

When I run it the `echo $a` print `sudo tcpdump "icmp"`, but when `$a` is executed, I get the error. When I copy paste the printed message, the command just run normally.

I also tried to put the command in an array and execute it by calling : `${array[@]}`, but it didn't solve the problem.

Does someone have a solution?

Comment: Use `a='sudo tcpdump icmp'`. The shell doesn't re-parse what it has already parsed; after expanding `$a` it does not go again over the expanded text and re-parse it; as a result, the shell does not strip away the `"` characters; `tcpdump` sees the `"` character and complains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
eval "$a"
```

according to `man bash`

> ```
>    eval [arg ...]
>           The args are read and concatenated together into a single command.  This command is then read and executed by the shell, and its exit status is returned  as  the  value  of
>           eval.  If there are no args, or only null arguments, eval returns 0.
> ```